# Filter out array of object from array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have the following data

```
const[myData,setMyData]=React.useState([])
React.useEffect(()=>{
 let initialData=[{ email: 'user1@mail.com', date: '22-03-2020' },
   { email: 'user2@mail.com', date: '22-03-2021' },
   { email: 'user3@mail.com', date: '22-03-2021' }]
 setMyData(initialData)
},[])
```

this data are displayed in a table with a checkbox and I have this function called everytime I push a button (after having the rows selected)

```
function add(datatoRemove ){
  alert("datatoRemove "+JSON.stringify(datatoRemove ) )
  let myArrayFiltered = myData.filter((el) => {
    return datatoRemove .some((f) => {
      return f.email!== el.email
    });
  });
  alert("filtered"+JSON.stringify(myArrayFiltered ) )

  setMyData( [...myArrayFiltered ])    
}
```

The issue is that with one selection the "myArrayFiltered " returns the other 2 rows and the state is updated correctly but if I select two or all the row nothing changed and the  myArrayFiltered  have all 3 elements.
What am I missing here?

the final goal is:

**possible scenario 1:**
if

```
datatoRemove = [{ email: 'user1@mail.com', date: '22-03-2020' },
       { email: 'user2@mail.com', date: '22-03-2021' },
       { email: 'user3@mail.com', date: '22-03-2021' }]
```

then

`myArrayFiltered=[]` and also the `myData= []`

**possible scenario 2:**

```
if datatoRemove = [ { email: 'user2@mail.com', date: '22-03-2021' },{ 
email: 'user3@mail.com', date: '22-03-2021' }]
```

then

`myArrayFiltered= [{ email: 'user1@mail.com', date: '22-03-2020' }]`

and also myData.

Comment: I update my question with like 2 possible scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this instead

```
let myArrayFiltered = initialData.filter((el) => {
  return datatoRemove.every((f) => {
    return f.email!= el.email
  });
});
```